# Is it possible to control CPU cores?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture

**If I own quad core processor, can I "isolate" or totally control 1 core from other cores?**

The fourth core job is to serve only and only for allocated thread and nothing else.

What I want is to do thread that job is get to get numbers from memory, from always same physical adresses and calculate them how I want and put them back to the same place. (I will disable virtual memory)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: taskset lets you specify which core.  Running without VM is hard.  What OS will you use?

Comment: No matter actually,  I have OS X, windows, freeBSD and linux.

Comment: I'll use the OS which is best choice for this job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, you can use the `sched_setaffinity` function to do this.  Set the affinity for the special thread to `8` (i.e. `0b1000`) and the other threads to `7` (i.e. `0b0111`).

You're probably SOL if you really want to switch off virtual memory or anything like that.  However, you may be able to write a kernel driver whose job is to expose the relevant section of physical memory to your user program.

Comment: Will this method ensure that other part of OS will not be able to use  that core?

Comment: @user3521129 No it won't. If you want absolutely nothing to touch that core, I believe you need to write your own OS. There might to disable the core in the BIOS and expose it to a driver. But that's out of my league.

Comment: @user3521129: I don't know what you're doing, but I probably wouldn't worry about that at this stage.  If it turns out to be a problem, though, you might try horsing around with kernel settings regarding which processors handle interrupts from which devices.